# Copy/Pasting to different workbook after filtering table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to apply filter on a table on 1 field, then copy and paste the values to another workbook.I used a code below. But its not working.

Due to to big data the excel suddenly stops responding. How to change the code. Help me

```
sub createfilter()

Dim FiltRng As Range Dim RngArea As Range

Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="DE", Operator:=xlFilterValues

For Each RngArea In Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

If RngArea.Row > 1 Then
    If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
        Set FiltRng = Application.Union(FiltRng, RngArea)
    Else
        Set FiltRng = RngArea
    End If End If

Next RngArea

If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
    FiltRng.Copy
    Windows("Land-DE.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Overall view").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False End If

End sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't use Copy and Paste (not the best way to transfer data) but should do what you want

```
Sub createfilter()
    Dim Results As Variant, tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim CriteriaCol As Long, ResultCount As Long
    Dim Criteria As String

    Criteria = "DE"
    CriteriaCol = 12

    With Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable")
        tmp = .DataBodyRange
    End With

    ReDim Results(LBound(tmp, 2) To UBound(tmp, 2), LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1))
    For i = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
        If UCase(tmp(i, CriteriaCol)) = UCase(Criteria) Then
            ResultCount = ResultCount + 1
            j = LBound(tmp, 2) - 1
            Do
                j = j + 1
                Results(j, ResultCount) = tmp(i, j)
            Loop Until j = UBound(tmp, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve Results(LBound(Results, 1) To UBound(Results, 1), LBound(Results, 1) To ResultCount)
    With Workbooks("Land-DE.xlsx").Sheets("Overall view")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Results, 2), UBound(Results, 1)) = Application.Transpose(Results)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is almost working. The problem is, creating empty rows. In my raw data i have 100000 rows. After filtering it is 10000. But when i am pasting in another workbook, then 10000 row values are coming but creating 100000 rows. where 90000 are empty. Can you help me to solve this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying my code is creating additional empty rows or that you want to create empty rows?

Comment: Do you use the variable `i` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Can you try my updated. There's no reason for it to create additional Empty Rows.

Answer (score 2):

Only the non-filtered rows are copied by default:

```
Sub createfilter()

    Dim r As Range : Set r = Sheet2.Range("DataTable")

    r.AutoFilter 12, "DE", xlFilterValues

    If r.Height Then r.Copy ['[Land-DE.xlsx]Overall view'!A1]

End Sub
```

---

Update with `PasteSpecial` (not tested) :

```
Sub CreateFilter()
    With Sheet2.Range("DataTable")

        .AutoFilter 12, "DE", xlFilterValues

        If .Height Then .Copy Else Exit Sub 
    End With

    With ['[Land-DE.xlsx]Overall view'!A1]
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I just want to paste the values alone. How can i add `Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False` 
`Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: the excel suddenly stops responding

Comment: When i am using pastespecial, excel either working very slowly or suddenly stops responding.

Comment: @Deepak is my first version without pastespecial faster? I don't think there is any easy way to make it faster ..

Answer (score 1):

You can also just copy the filtered range.

```
    Sub Copy_FilteredRange()
    Dim FiltRng As Range, RngArea As Range, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks("Land-DE.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Overall view")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="DE", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Sheet2.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```