# Skipping copy of table when filter has no data

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have been building a large macro, and it uses tables to transfer some filtered data. When the table filters apply a filter and there is no positive results in the table the entire data set in the table is copied instead of nothing.

I have some ideas but they are starting to become complex and I have a series of tables using this method, so I am looking for a simpler way of avoiding a full data copy of values not intended to be copied.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("iexp_period").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1 _
    :=Array("Asset", "Asset(Rc)", "LVP", "LVP(Rc)"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Range("iexp_period").Copy
```

So as stated if the table has no filtered results this copy copies the entire table's data even though all rows are hidden when copied.

Is there a quick way to  avoid this please?

Comment: What software package is this macro for? What are you asking about? It is not clear.

Comment: you can check the data range height https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341102/copy-pasting-to-different-workbook-after-filtering-table/48343175#48343175

Comment: Thanks Slai! 

One small line of code is the solution, within a with statement.


If .Height Then .Copy Else Exit Sub

Answer (score 0):

Iam not to sure since Iam an newbie to VBA myself but when i just researched a similar issue and this: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?40514-How-to-exclude-hidden-rows-columns-while-executing-a-VB-code helped me out a lot.

I assume that rows.hidden would be the method you are looking for? Maybe you need to negate it.

Here would be some additional example code (from allen wyatt not me!)

```
Sub NumberClients()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer

    If Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Only select the cells you want numbered"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    j = 0
    For Each c In Selection
        If Not c.Rows.Hidden Then
            j = j + 1
            c.Value = j
        Else
            c.Clear
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

I hope this helps you a little :)